# jest-haste-map:Duplicate module name: react-animated

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-animated, metro-bundler

After adding `react-native-push-notification` and `@react-native-community/push-notification-ios` I am facing the error:

```
Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-animated
  Paths: /<projectPath>/node_modules/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json collides with /<projectPath>/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json

This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for different files.
    at setModule (/<projectPath>/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:569:17)
    at workerReply (/<projectPath>/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:641:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 77)
```

- I did [add blacklist](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21242#issuecomment-445784118) to `rn-cli.config.js`
- cleared yarn cache, removed node_modules, cleared watchman and re-run

None helped.

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.10",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.2.0",
"react-native-push-notification": "^3.5.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

I did add the blacklist to **`metro.config.js`**  NOT `rn-cli.config.js`

```
// metro.config.js
var blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
    resolver: {
        blacklistRE: blacklist([
            /node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/,
        ])
    },
};
```